# Using multiple Routes and Controllers on single blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created multiple controller and routes but they are working 1 at a time, I have to disable the other and change the code of my blade file or use different blade file for them but is there an easy way to use it.

The routes are

```
Route::get('/students/{alphabet}', 'PostController@showByAlphabet');
Route::get('/students/{name}', 'PostController@showByName');
Route::get('/students/{class}', 'PostController@showByClass');
```

I do not want to create different blade files like

```
http://example.com/students/alphabet/a
http://example.com/students/name/nadia
http://example.com/students/class/b_com
```

but like this

```
http://example.com/students/a
http://example.com/students/nadia
http://example.com/students/b_com
```

is it possible?

All controllers show different data. 
1. Alphabet show list of students starting with same initial.
2. Name shows profile data of the student.
3. Class shows list of students in that subject class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a wildcard at the end of your routes the first one will always trigger. So make sure you have individual routes for the controller functions. You can still use the same blade file in the controller.

```
Route::get('/students/alphabet/{alphabet}', 'PostController@showByAlphabet');
Route::get('/students/name/{name}', 'PostController@showByName');
Route::get('/students/class/{class}', 'PostController@showByClass');
```

If you have the same route with a parameter there is no way for the router to know if the characters you're sending in are alphabet, name or class.